# I can't delete AWS appconfig configuration and environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-app-config

I'm studying about `Appconfig` to change my service from `parameter store` to `Appconfig`.

I have **two applications in AWS Appconfig want to delete.**

1.

- application : **TestApp**
- configuration(0 EA) : None
- environment(1 EA) : **test (has 2 deployments with deleted configurations)**

-> I can't delete `test` environment though I don't have any configuration under this app. There are 2 deployments under `test`, but I deleted it.

```
BadRequestException: Cannot delete environment 
arn:aws:appconfig:ap-northeast-2:*****:application/*****/environment/*****
because there are extensions associated with it.
Please remove the extension associations to this environment first.
```

[image]

[image]

2.

- application : **develop-config**
- configuration(1 EA) : **kakao (no flag configuration)**
- environment(0 EA) : None

There is no flag in configuration, and no any deployed environments but I can't delete `kakao` configuration. I got error as bellow when I've tried to delete `kakao` configuration

```
BadRequestException: Cannot delete configuration profile
arn:aws:appconfig:ap-northeast-2:*****:application/*****/configurationprofile/*****
because there are extensions associated with it.
Please remove the extension associations to this configuration profile first.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've created lambda function to test appconfig, but I deleted every lambda function and permission policy now. I think there is no extensions associated with these, But I still can't delete these applications.

Can I check every associated extensions with appconfig? Or is there any different way to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list the extension associations related to your appconfig applications by using the aws cli:

```
aws appconfig list-extension-associations
```

Identify the extensions related to the appconfig application/environment you want to delete then delete these extension-associations using the aws cli again:

```
aws appconfig delete-extension-association --extension-association-id ewcd2yo
```

where **ewcd2yo** is our extension id from the list we got above.

Once all extensions linked to a given appconfig app are completely deleted, then you can successfully delete the app or environment.

Note: your aws cli must be configured to use the same region as the one you deployed your appconfig apps.